# Combining IFAND with another IF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to combine a couple of different formulas here that reference a "days since" column. Anything between a certain range would return "training needed" and anything beyond that range would return "training overdue".

These two separate formulas work independently but I cannot figure out how to nest them together to function properly.

Is this doable or are we looking at too many arguments?

The two functioning formulas are:

```
=IF(G10>1095,"OVERDUE","none")

=IF(AND(G10>=1050,G10<=1095),"TRAINING NEEDED","")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=XLOOKUP($G9,{0,1050,1096},{"none","TRAINING NEEDED","OVERDUE"},"",-1)
```

The formula takes the value in column G and compares it to the first array. It matches against an exact match or the next smallest item. So, values between 0 and 1049 are matched against the first array item, which returns the first array item from the second array (i.e. "none"). Values between 1050 and 1095 are matched against the second array item, which returns "TRAINING NEEDED" and values greater than 1095 (i.e. 1096 and above) are matched against the third array item.

You can also use this:

```
=IFS($G9<1050,"none",$G9<1096,"TRAINING NEEDED",true,"OVERDUE")
```

I prefer `XLOOKUP` because if you choose to add many more conditions, it's more compact. Both will work:

[image]

Comment: Didn't even think about XLOOKUP, thank you so much!  Works perfectly